# create multiple threads in two infinite loops simultaneously

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm learning C and pthread library but I have a problem starting two threads in functions with an infinite loop.

The second pthread_create is never called.
How to create both threads?

My code looks like

```
void* func1() {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func1");
    sleep(2);
  }
}
void* func2() {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func2");
    sleep(2);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_t thread_id2;
  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, func1(), NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, func2(), NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong function signature. `void* func1()` should be `void* func1(void*)`. And in pthread_create you call the function instead of passing the address to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, your program does not compile on my machine unless I fix some of the issues. Most notably, you need to pass the function not call the function, so you must remove the parenthesis after `func1` and `func2` in the `pthread_create` calls. A working version of the code that doesn't produce any errors/warnings (just some types that are irrelevant in this case, but in general pthreads seem to want everything to be `void*`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* func1(void*) {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func1");
    sleep(2);
  }
}

void* func2(void*) {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func2");
    sleep(2);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_t thread_id2;
  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, func1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, func2, NULL);
  //sleep(60);
  return 0;
}
```

And now for your issue, as stated in the documentation (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) all threads will exit if the main thread of the program exits - as it does in your case.

So, your program (once we help it compile) **does** try to create a second thread, but there is some overhead associated with that and it never actually manages to print before `return 0;` is reached in `main`. This causes the program to exit and you never see the output of the second thread. A simple fix is to add another `sleep` command after you create the threads, this gives them enough time to print.

Comment: Unlike C++, C (up to C11, at least) requires parameters to have names.  So just give them names: `void* func1(void *unused)`, etc.  That will reduce the error to a mere warning.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to init the thread attributes using pthread_attr_init also you tell main to wait until child thread finishes using pthread_join.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
void *func1(void *p) {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func1");
    sleep(2);
  }
}

void *func2(void *p) {
  while (1) {
    printf("%s\n", "func2");
    sleep(2);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_t thread_id2;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &func1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id2, &attr, &func2, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id2,NULL);


  //sleep(60);
  return 0;
}
```